# JSON Extract : Output upstream columns in JSON array node

Tags: ssis, kingswaysoft

I use JSON Extract from the SSIS library KingswaySoft to parse a JSON content.

From the root JSON, I can output the input columns (named upstreams) :
[image]

But it don't look possible from a array node :
[image]

How can output the input columns in the array node output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the upstream is only available on the root output. The solution is to merge the node array output with root output.

In the node array output add the `_ParentKeyField` :
[image]

This column take the value from root's column specify in "Output Settings" (by default `_RowIndex`) :
[image]

The merge need the output to be sorted. Open the JSON Extract with "Show Advanced Editor...". In the tab "Input and Output Properties",
set the property `IsSorted` to `true` for the output "Root" and " :
[image]

Set the property `SortKeyPosition` to `1` for :

- Root\Output Columns\_RowIndex
- <node array output>\Output Columns\_ParentKeyField
  [image]

In the flow, add the a "Merge join" and redirect the root output to left join and the node array output to right join. Configure to join on "_RowIndex=_ParentKeyField" :
[image]

Finally, you can select the desired column :
[image]